# Error handler for data type double

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on the error handling parts of my code.

How can I accept only numbers and period for my textbox?

for example. The user enters 25.00 its acceptable

I already have a textbox that only allows numbers but I don't know how to accept with decimals.

I'm using jquery inline validation

```
<asp:TextBox class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" type="text" ID="txtLicRic"  runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="230px" placeholder="123" Enabled="False" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for the Decimal case with jQuery inline validation

```
$.validator.addMethod('DecimalNumbersOnly', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(value); 
}, "Enter a correct decimal number, format xxxx.xx");
```

Answer (score -1):

can you try:

```
string s = "25.00"; //MAKE THIS YOUR TEXTBOX VALUE
decimal d;
if (Decimal.TryParse(s,out d))
{
    //HANDLE DECIMAL
}
```